# Auto Load and Refresh Div every 10 Seconds with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with a nice little Jquery that auto loads and refreshes a div every bla bla Seconds.
Works perfectly on all browsers then I load up IE and bang what a surprise no luck! :(

Index.html

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#load').load('reload.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds

<body>
<div id="load"> </div>
</body>

</script>
```

reload.php

```
<?

echo time(); //just a timestamp example..

?>
```

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a random value at the end of the url to avoid caching.. That should solve your problem. ex: `$('#load').load('reload.php?_=' +Math.random()).fadeIn("slow");`

Comment: wow nice! should have came here after the first hour trying to figure it out

Comment: or use jquery's $.ajax() function with cache: false, could be a bit overkill though. But I highly recommend that you send http headers in reload.php, which "deactivate" caching.

Answer (score 4):

Try closing your script tag before having your body tag.

```
<head>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#load').load('reload.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="load"> </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  body {text-align:center; background-image: url('http://cdn3.crunchify.com/wp- content/uploads/2013/03/Crunchify.bg_.300.png')}


    $(document).ready(function() {
        auto_refresh();
    });
    function auto_refresh(){
        var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        $('#show').text('I am getting refreshed every 3 seconds..! Random Number ==> '+ randomnumber);
    }
    var refreshId = setInterval(auto_refresh, 1000);
```