# Ajax - Div Refresh Even When Code is Deleted

Tags: jquery, ajax, refresh

First, the site : [www.gallerymodules.com](http://www.gallerymodules.com/)

At one point, I had a div at the bottom that would refresh every 10 seconds to update a counter. I noticed that this was placing a huge load on my server, and removed the div and the corresponding Ajax code from the site header. However, I'm still seeing gobs of requests to the page that handled the refresh, even though the code is no longer there. These requests are overrunning my apache logs.  Is there any way to force them to stop? They seem to be coming from IPs that are not active on the site (based on the fact that they haven't requested the index page, yet are still triggering the ajax updates).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Need more information. Where was the code that started the gallery, what was the code, etc. Whats the referring page? Perhaps someone hotlinked or copied the javascript.

Comment: remove the server side code which used to respond to the ajax request.

Comment: Darren-The code was in the main jquery code in the <head> of the index.php page.  It was something along the lines of the 2nd reply here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121285/auto-load-and-refresh-div-every-10-seconds-with-jquery .

The referer is the index page of my site, not a 3rd party site.

archmage - The server-side code is used for other functions, though I suppose I could rename the file that the zombie ajax is calling and modify the few lines in other places with a new filename.

Comment: OK, renamed the file that was called, just started a flood of 404s in the logs now...

Comment: Hmm, best guess is that maybe it got cached by some proxy server maybe? Pretty bizarre.

Comment: I thought that, but the IPs are literally all over the map...

Comment: You might just want to turn off Apache's logging for that specific page: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/env.html#logging -- hopefully those clients will eventually request your newer content and stop harassing your server, but in the meantime you can stop logging them.

Comment: Yeah, if only I had that level of control over the server.  C'est la vie.  The numbers seem to be dwindling, so hopefully by the end of the week, it'll stop.

Comment: Would a redirect via .htaccess to the main page (that has the new non-refresh code) work? Or would it cause some sort of horrendous loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did: 
1. Renamed the file that was being called by the zombie ajax code.
2. I created a 301 redirect in my .htaccess redirecting from the old file to the site index.

This avoided a flood of 404s in my logs, and seemed to trigger the offending clients to realize that the code had changed, and has resolved the issue.