# how to refresh div with ajax by its id every seconds

Tags: html, comments, autoload, reply

```
   <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="getrep.js"></script>
    <div id="item-1">
     <p>this is first comment</p>
     <div class="reply" id="reply-1">
        //--- reply goes here
        //-- this div updates by its id
  </div>


  <div id="item-45">
       <p>this is second comment</p>
      <div class="reply" id="reply-45">
        //--- reply goes here
        //-- this div updates by its id
  </div>

  <div id="item-55">
       <p>this is third comment</p>
      <div class="reply" id="reply-55">
        //--- reply goes here
        //-- this div updates by its id
  </div>
```

process.php here

```
   <?php 
     // php file to get reply every second
     $repId = $_GET['id'];  // i want this value given by ajax
     $getRep = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reply WHERE repliedon='$repId' ORDER BY id DESC");
     while ($rowRep = mysql_fetch_assoc($getRep))
     {
        echo '<p>'.$rowRep['content'].'</p>';
        }
    ?>
```

each div has different id value, so i want process.php file update
 each div with its reply every second without reloading whole page
 only reload DIV.CLASS repl. each div id is the id value of database
 and contains reply.thanks and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: What did your investigations show? There are many duplicates out there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto Load and Refresh Div every 10 Seconds with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121285/auto-load-and-refresh-div-every-10-seconds-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a technology/form of Javascript called Ajax. But specifically how you would use it, and how we'd be able to answer your question more specifically, does depend on which (if any) Javascript libraries you are using. Do you have any code for Javascript so far? If you don't, you'll probably want to close the question and look up other ones concerning Ajax and how to get started with this.

A Google search for "Ajax" or "Ajax tutorial" will find you a lot of results. I would advise that, if you aren't already using it, that you look into using the jQuery library, as it standardises Ajax, a technology which in its raw form is kind of messy. A tutorial focusing on using Ajax in jQuery can be found [here](http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/).

Comment: The technology you are wanting to use is still Ajax. Ajax is an asynchronous Javascript technology that is used to make HTTP calls without reloading the page. You cannot do what you are wanting to do through PHP alone; you need to have some sort of code to be able to call the PHP script without reloading the page. That's what Ajax does. Please read more about Ajax to determine how best you can use it to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i had used in my previous project
call the `done()` function in `$(document).ready()`

```
$(document).ready( function() {
 done(); 
});
```

In the `done()` below we call  `setTimeout()`which then calls the `updates()` (You can enter your code that you want to update every sec in the `updates()`)

```
function done() {
  setTimeout( function() { 
  updates(); 
  done();//call done() again
  }, 200);//refresh it accordingly
```

}

```
function updates() {
//Your code you want to update
```

}

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

check this link for setTimeout()