# Show a txt file on a webpage which updates every second in the webpage

Tags: javascript, html, file, text

I have searched for 5+ hours on this site and tried every code possible on getting this to work. I found a code on here that does pull info from a text file but it displays it into a box. What im trying to do is for it to be displayed inside the page not inside a popup box and to update every second. Also trying to display more than 1 .txt document in horizontal order if possible. Anyone know how I can alter this so it will display properly?

Currently shows this:

[what it currently showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meRVD.png)

[what Im trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgrLM.png)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks so much for your help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<Body>

<p><center>Current Track: <span id="trackinfo">No track information available at this time</span></p></center>

<script>
function radioTitle() {

var url = 'localhost/text.txt'; 

jQuery.get('http://localhost/text.txt', function(data) {
alert(data);
});

$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: url,
   dataType: 'text',
   success: function(data) {

   $("#trackinfo").html(data)
},

error: function(e) {
   console.log(e.message);
}
});

}

$(document).ready(function(){

setTimeout(function(){radioTitle();}, 2000);
setInterval(function(){radioTitle();}, 15000);

});

</script>

</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: I suggest you at least add a language tag to this

Comment: it was pulled and edited from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33942769/read-text-file-and-display-in-web-page

Comment: Nevermind, I found an answer to this problem using a HTML+PHP solution with jQuery's. Thanks anyway