# about DB and span class

Tags: php, html, database

I've just started to learn programming to be able to do changes to my site so i dont know much yet.

My question is I have this script:

```
<h4 style="border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;"><?php echo $winnername ?></h4>
<span class="val"><?php echo $msg[$lang]["win"]; ?>:</span>
<span class="price">$<?php echo round($winnercost,2); ?></span>
```

Is it possible to make it auto update when a new winner is chosen, because now you have to reload site for it to update.

This is the first part where it grabs info

```
<?php 
        $lastgame = fetchinfo("value","info","name","current_game");
        $lastwinner = fetchinfo("userid","games","id",$lastgame-1);
        $winnercost = fetchinfo("cost","games","id",$lastgame-1);
        $winnerpercent = round(fetchinfo("percent","games","id",$lastgame-1),1);
        $winneravatar = fetchinfo("avatar","users","steamid",$lastwinner);
        $winnername = fetchinfo("name","users","steamid",$lastwinner);
?>
```

Comment: please, update question tags with php too.

Comment: Yes you can, there are some different ways, the easiest I think, is using ajax and jQuery. 
I know this isn't an answer, but maybe it could give you a suggest about where to search.
Ajax could update that span element every x seconds for example, without refresh the entire page.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys got it working now :)

Answer (score 1):

PHP only generates a page server-side and sends them to the client. Auto refreshing the generated page is managed client-side, so you must use Javascript for this.

You will use Ajax for auto refreshing part of the page. Create a PHP script that only returns the new data (the html content for the tag `<h4>`), and use something like [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506873/change-div-content-using-ajax-php-and-jquery) from another question.

If you use that script, instead of using `onclick` to fire the refresh, you can call it automatically using `setInterval()`:

```
<script>
  setInterval(function() {
    getSummary();
  },60000);
</script>
```

This will refresh the data every minute.

Answer (score 0):

Use this script from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121285/auto-load-and-refresh-div-every-10-seconds-with-jquery)

This script use jquery to change the content of the div (#load) every 10 seconds, taking the value from the file reload.php with your database query.

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#load').load('reload.php');
}, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds

<body>
<div id="load"></div>
</body>

</script>
```

In case you decide to use this method. Take a look to the original question, cause it could be doesn't work with IE without a little patch.

Comment: Is it not possible to make it just reload a div part of the index.php file? the ones i have found need another .php file